# jQuery: Verify If one of multiple required checkboxes is/are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, checkbox

I have a form with multiple groups of checkboxes (among other things). Some of these groups are mandatory fields (At least one checkbox needs to be checked within that group).

I am able to tell if a group has a checkbox checked, but I failed to make them mandatory. Also I am need to get one long string with the values of the selected checkbox(es). I would need to have a string where if the user checks, say the first 3 checkboxes from group1, the string to be:

"zero | 1 val | 2 val"

The code is a simplified version of my original. Here is the jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QyY2P/1/

Also, for your convenience I am also including the code here:

**jQuery**:

```
function countChecked() {
    //Group 1
    var n = $("#group1 input:checked").length;
    $("#count").text(n + (n <= 1 ? " is" : " are") + " checked!");
    $("#group1 input:checked").each(function() {
        txt += ($(this).val() + " | ");
        $("#selection1").text(txt);
        alert($(this).val() + " | ");
    });


    //Group 2
    var n = $("#group2 input:checked").length;
    $("#count").text(n + (n <= 1 ? " is" : " are") + " checked!");
    $("#group2 input:checked").each(function() {
        txt += ($(this).val() + " | ");
        $("#selection3").text(txt);
        alert($(this).val() + " | ");
    });
}

countChecked();
$(":checkbox").click(countChecked);
```

**HTML**:

```
<form>
  <div id="group1">
    <p> *Please select a box (Mandatory)</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ckb_unit[]" value="zero" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="ckb_unit[]" value="1 val" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="ckb_unit[]" value="2 val" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="ckb_unit[]" value="3 val" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="ckb_unit[]" value="4 val" />
  </div>


  <div id="group2">
      <p>Please select a box</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ckb_unit[]" value="zero" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="ckb_unit[]" value="A" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="ckb_unit[]" value="B" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="ckb_unit[]" value="C" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="ckb_unit[]" value="D" />
  </div>

  <div id="group3">
    <p>*Please select a box (Mandatory)</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ckb_unit[]" value="zero" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="ckb_unit[]" value="1 A" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="ckb_unit[]" value="2 B" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="ckb_unit[]" value="3 C" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="ckb_unit[]" value="4 D" />
  </div>
</form>

<!-- For debugging purposes -->
<br/>
<div id="count"></div>
<div id="selection1"></div>
<div id="selection3"></div>
```

PS. I am a beginner, perhaps you noticed it by my not so elegant coding >_<

Comment: @roobeedeedada thank you roobeedeedada! I am still refining the jquery code, but this is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/QyY2P/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can make it mandatory by checking if n is 0 when the user hits submit and then attracting the user's attention towards it somehow (appending an error message, for example). I'm talking about this n:

```
var n = $("#group1 input:checked").length;
```

Looking at JSFiddle, it seems you didn't declare txt as a variable, so this works for me:

```
//Group 1
var txt = ""; // initialise txt with an empty string, so you can append to it later
var n = $("#group1 input:checked").length;
$("#count").text(n + (n <= 1 ? " is" : " are") + " checked!");
$("#group1 input:checked").each(function() {
    txt += ($(this).val() + " | ");
    $("#selection1").text(txt);
    alert($(this).val() + " | ");
});
```

Comment: how can I remove the last pattern: " | "?
. Ej. if the user selected 2 chkbx, I'd like the string to be "zero | 1 val" instead of "zero | 1 val | "?

Comment: Store your values in an array then use the .join(" | ") method to turn them into one big string. Here's a helpful link: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp